# Can't detected bounding rect of id card

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, canny-operator

I want to detect the bounding rectangle of an German ID card within an image by using OpenCV.

This is what my code looks like:

```
    capture >> frame;

   
    cv::resize(frame, frame, cv::Size(512,256));
    cv::Mat grayScaledFrame, blurredFrame, cannyFrame;
    cv::cvtColor(frame, grayScaledFrame, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::GaussianBlur(grayScaledFrame, blurredFrame, cv::Size(9,9), 1);

    cv::Canny(blurredFrame, cannyFrame, 40, 70);

    // CONTOURS
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    cv::findContours(cannyFrame, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // SORT
    int maxArea = 0;
    std::vector<cv::Point> contour;

    for(int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        int thisArea = cv::contourArea(contours.at(i));
        if(thisArea > maxArea) {
            maxArea = thisArea;
            contour = contours.at(i);
        }
    }
    cv::Rect borderBox = cv::boundingRect(contour);

    cv::rectangle(cannyFrame, borderBox, cv::Scalar{255, 32, 32}, 8);
    cv::imshow("Webcam", cannyFrame);
```

The result looks like this:
[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsuxw.png)

There are some rectangles detected but not the big one I'm interested in.
I've already tried different thresholds for Canny and also different kernel sizes for Gaussian Blur.

Best regards

Comment: everyone tries to detect cards from webcam video. what do others differently that they appear to have better results? present your literature review

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as the environmental conditions change, the parameters of the code change, so it is necessary to standardize the environment (light, distance to the object, etc.).
To get this detection right, put the card at a fixed distance from the camera and calculate the area of the rectangles.
When the card is at a certain distance from the camera, you get approximate reference values of the card's area. Then, when drawing a rectangle, you use values within a specified tolerance range.